# No such device or address - Linux device driver development

Tags: linux-device-driver, kernel-module

When I try to `cat /dev/gpio-reflect`, I get the error: 
`No such device or address`

`cat proc/devices` lists my driver with the correct major number.

`dmesg` prints the logs form the init and exit functions.

I also created the corresponding file under /dev (major is correct).

`cdev_add` and `alloc_chrdev_region` don't return error codes.

I don't know what i am doing wrong. Please help me.

```
static struct file_operations fops = {
.owner = THIS_MODULE,
.read = device_read,
.write = device_write,
.open = device_open,
.release = device_release
};


static int __init gpio_reflect_init(void)
{

int err,res=alloc_chrdev_region(&dev, 0, 1, dname);
classptr = class_create(THIS_MODULE, "socledclass");
device_create(classptr, NULL, MAJOR(dev), NULL, dname);
cdev_init(&c_dev, &fops);
c_dev.ops=&fops;
c_dev.owner=THIS_MODULE;
err=cdev_add(&c_dev, MAJOR(dev), 1);

if(err){
    printk(KERN_INFO "Could not add device");
}

if(res<0){
    printk(KERN_INFO "Could not alloc device");
    return res;
}else{
    printk(KERN_INFO "Major: %i",MAJOR(dev));
}
printk(KERN_INFO "Input Pin is: %i\n",in);
printk(KERN_INFO "Output Pin is: %i\n",out);


return 0;
}

static void __exit gpio_reflect_cleanup(void)
{
cdev_del(&c_dev);
unregister_chrdev_region(dev,1);
printk(KERN_INFO "%s unloaded\n",dname);

}

static int device_open(struct inode *inode, struct file *file)
{
printk(KERN_INFO "open\n");
if (Device_Open)
    return -EBUSY;

Device_Open++;
sprintf(msg, "Hello\n");
msg_Ptr = msg;
try_module_get(THIS_MODULE);

return SUCCESS;
}

static int device_release(struct inode *inode, struct file *file)
{
printk(KERN_INFO "release\n");
Device_Open--;

module_put(THIS_MODULE);

return SUCCESS;
}

 static ssize_t device_read(struct file *filp, char *buffer,size_t length,  loff_t * offset){
int bytes_read = 0;
printk(KERN_INFO "read\n");

if (*msg_Ptr == 0)
    return 0;
while (length && *msg_Ptr) {
    put_user(*(msg_Ptr++), buffer++);

    length--;
    bytes_read++;
}
return bytes_read;
}


static ssize_t
device_write(struct file *filp, const char *buff, size_t len, loff_t *       off)
{
printk(KERN_INFO "write\n");
printk(KERN_ALERT "Sorry, this operation isn't supported.\n");
return -EINVAL;
}

module_init(gpio_reflect_init);
module_exit(gpio_reflect_cleanup);
```

Sorry for the badly formatted code :)

Comment: I guess the best approach is to read a code example. Perhaps a book like LDD3 will help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case anyone has the same problem.
It was just a stupid mistake.

wrong: `cdev_add(&c_dev, MAJOR(dev), 1);`

right: `cdev_add(&c_dev, dev, 1);`

Answer (score 0):

If your device node under `/dev/` is `/dev/gpio-reflect` try `cat /dev/gpio-reflect`